# Privately synchronising calendar files between platforms

Tags: encryption, sync, android, calendar, ics

**Introduction**

I would like to be able to maintain a calendar *privately*, using offline calendar applications on both my Android mobile and Windows/Linux desktop computers.

I understand that cloud services tend to scrape events from any user's hosted calendars for various reasons, including providing recommendations to the user.

However, in avoiding cloud services, there is a manual effort in copying ics files via a local connection and merging changes periodically.

**Question**

Are there any popular methods to sync a calendar file privately between platforms, with or without the use of cloud services?

For instance, it is possible to encrypt the calendar, host it on a domain, and to access from both sides via SFTP. It might also still be possible to use existing services here - say by syncing a locally encrypted calendar with a private key not known to Google.

So I would like to know either if there are existing implementations of this or if anyone has suggestions of alternative approaches.

Comment: Yes it is possible. The problem with this question is that in asking for recommendations for a solution there is no one empirical and best option. Based on your particular needs the correct answer for you could be very different from the correct answer for someone else. SuperUser is not designed for this sort of question. It IS designed to solve specific and answerable problems and question. So, if you have chosen a solution and are working on implementing it and are having a specific problem, THAT'S something we may be able to help you with.

Comment: Also, a tip: It is not necessarily the Cloud itself that is the problem. If you were to leverage a cloud service, to synchronize a file that your various apps on your various systems can then read to show your calendar content, that would be a relatively easy way to get around this scraping you're worried about. All that remains is to select applications that read such a sync-able file type.